# Listening on the data between a process and a serial port

Tags: tty, arm, serial-port

I have a process that is using /dev/ttyAMA2 port to communicate with an external device on a PCB.

What options do I have of listening to the communication between a process and a serial port, on an ARM processor and a read-only file system (except /home) without interfering with their communication?

Other question suggested using `socat` or `interceptty` but I was not able to cross-compile it for that processor. But I can compile my own c code and successfully run it.

All I need is to get what the process is sending to that port (I don't need the response data).